# SIP and ZRTP objective c libraries

Tags: ios6, sip

I want to use SIP and ZRTP protocols in my application . I have not found one objective c library/framework which has both of these implemented..

Although I'm aware of these protocols that are available separately like idoubs which uses SIP or icall which has ZRTP integration. I also went through the PJSIP - ZRTP integration from the site http://www.zrtp.org/pjsip-integration, but that integration is also somehow not happening. it shows errors

I want to know is there any other available approach to this problem.

**EDIT :** I have found a couple of more libraries but they all have lots of errors

https://github.com/traviscross/libzrtp

http://www.qutecom.org/browser/verona/oRTP/src/zrtp.c?rev=519

I'm using doubango framework for VoIP and video calling and i want to integrate zrtp for that framework. I'm stuck as to how to implement this feature? Any help would be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that in SIP is media agnostic, why do you need a framework that uses both?

Use whatever ZRTP implementation you like, reserve the ports you need, and give the SIP implementation the constructed SDP for your INVITE.